# UIScrollView behaving differently in portrait mode and landscape mode

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiscrollview

i have created a UIScrollVIew(name-helpView) through XIB with the a size of (768,1800).
Now i am adding this to another view through the following code.

```
-(IBAction)showHelpView:(UIButton *)sender{

if(helpViewIsShowing==NO){
    //set the content size more than the view size to make the view scroll
    helpView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(helpView.frame.size.width, 2200);

    [self.view addSubview:helpView];
    helpButton.selected=YES;
    helpView.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    helpView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 41, helpView.frame.size.width, helpView.frame.size.height);
    helpViewIsShowing=YES;
}
else{

    [helpView removeFromSuperview];
    helpButton.selected=NO;
    helpViewIsShowing=NO;

}
```

}

The frame of the scrollview is appearing fine when i run it in portrait mode. Itz also working fine if i turn the device from to PORTRAIT TO LANDSCAPE. But if i run the the code in landscape mode, then the frame of the scrollview is not adjusting itself to the full screen size. i have also given a auto resizing mask through XIB. But no luck either. 
can anyone help me with this please.... Thanku

Comment: Pls check the contentSize of the scrollview when it starts in Landscape and see if its the one you want.

Comment: actually i have checked even through that way by giving it a different frame when i am in landscape mode. But even that dont seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to set the view frame in your view controller this function to the view size your required.you can define height and width according to your requirement.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
    if (interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        self.helpView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 703,768);    

        } else {
        self.helpView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024);
        }


    return YES;
}
```

good luck

Comment: thanku for the reply Kshitiz. i tried it this way but still it dont work. i found that the size of the ScrollView is not changing if we change it through code. The values which were specified in the XIB are being generated here. i tried to override those values through my code. But it dint work.. can you tell me some thing on this issue please

Comment: @ A for Alpha: i have noticed your have set frame size to 768 by 1800 but iPad screen size is 1024 by 768.did you try for ipad resolution,u are running app in ipad rite?

Comment: The ipad screen is 768*1024 but my view size is almost 768*1500 and i should set the content size more than my view size for it to scroll. that is the reason i gave that frame. is there something wrong with it??